# NestJS: Authorization (CASL) issue

Tags: nestjs, authorization, casl

The different user types:

```
export const enum USER_TYPE {
    SUPER_ADMIN = 'SUPER_ADMIN',
    ADMIN = 'ADMIN',
    COMPANY_ADMIN = 'COMPANY_ADMIN',
    STORE_ADMIN = 'STORE_ADMIN',
    MANAGER = 'MANAGER',
}
```

The AppAbility code using CASL approach

```
type Actions = 'manage' | 'create' | 'read' | 'update' | 'delete';
type Subjects = InferSubjects<typeof User> | 'all';

type AppAbility = MongoAbility<[Actions, Subjects]>;

const { can, cannot, build } = new AbilityBuilder<AppAbility>(createMongoAbility);

@Injectable()
export class UserAbilityFactory {
    createForUser(userType: USER_TYPE): MongoAbility {
        try {
            if (userType === USER_TYPE.SUPER_ADMIN) {
                can('manage', 'all');
            }

            if (userType === USER_TYPE.ADMIN) {
                cannot('create', User, {
                    userType: {
                        $eq: USER_TYPE.SUPER_ADMIN,
                    },
                });

                can('create', User, {
                    userType: {
                        $in: [USER_TYPE.COMPANY_ADMIN, USER_TYPE.STORE_ADMIN],
                    },
                });
            }

            return build();
        } catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    }
}
```

**I want the ADMIN user to be able to create users other than SUPER_ADMIN but it creates a SUPER_ADMIN user**

The user registration code:

```
@Post('register')
@UseGuards(RolesGuard)
@Roles(USER_TYPE.SUPER_ADMIN, USER_TYPE.ADMIN, USER_TYPE.COMPANY_ADMIN)
@HttpCode(201)
async register(@Body() userData: CreateUserDto): Promise<any> {
    try {
        const user = await firstValueFrom(this.userService.Signup(userData));
        return sendSuccess(user);
    } catch (error) {
        throw new BadRequestException(error.message);
    }
}
```

The AuthGuard code:

```
export const Roles = (...roles: USER_TYPE[]) => SetMetadata('roles', roles);

@Injectable()
export class RolesGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private readonly reflector: Reflector,
        private readonly jwtService: JwtService,
        private readonly redisService: RedisService,
        private readonly userAbilityFactory: UserAbilityFactory
    ) {}

    async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
        const requiredRoles = this.reflector.get<USER_TYPE[]>('roles', context.getHandler());
        if (!requiredRoles) return true;

        const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
        const bearerToken = request.headers.authorization;
        if (!bearerToken || !bearerToken.startsWith('Bearer ')) return false;

        const token = bearerToken.split(' ')[1];
        try {
            const decoded = this.jwtService.verifyAccessToken(token);
            const userRole = decoded.userType;

            const ability = this.userAbilityFactory.createForUser(userRole);

            const canAccess = ability.can('create', User);

            if (canAccess) {
                request.user = decoded;
                const userId = decoded.userId;
                const loggedIn = await this.redisService.getValue(userId);
                if (!loggedIn) return false;

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        } catch (error) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The canAccess variable always returns true.

What is it that I am doing wrong? I don't understand that. Does my code even check that what kind of user I want to create from the request body?

Comment: Hey John, have you tried passing the actual object to your permission check as I suggested in your other question?
So `const canAccess = ability.can('create', User)` would become something like `const canAccess = ability.can('create', request.body)`.
You need to validate against the actual object. Only request.body holds the information that ADMIN is trying to create a SUPER_ADMIN. 
Otherwise you are just checking if "Can the user create any other user", which is true in this case as ADMIN can create some users.

Comment: @astoiccoder Yes, I have tried that but now it says forbidden for every user that I want to create. Do I need to pass the whole request body object or just the user type that I want to create? because I have tried both and none of them are working

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing an answer here, so that I have more space. It might not be complete, but hopefully point you in the right direction.

I quickly put together a working example based on your code here https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/cocky-nash-ytfpyj.

Important to note here is

1. `const { can, cannot, build } = new AbilityBuilder<AppAbility>(createMongoAbility);` needs to be called inside your function `createForUser`. Otherwise the abilities will accumulate over several calls of that method, because the builder is created outside the function scope. You can test this in the sandbox if you move the creation of the builder outside the function, which will give you unexpected results.
2. For some reason that I can't explain, the MongoAbility and mongo query conditions only work when you define the abilities via string, i.e. `"User"` instead of `User`. With the latter the conditions just don't work. For using strings you need to define the Subjects as `type Subjects = User | "User" | "all";`
3. In your case, you would always want to pass objects to `ability.can()`, because you want to know if your current user can create a specific user payload.
4. When you want to pass `request.body` which is of type `CreateUserDto` like this `ability.can('create', request.body)`, you might need to change everything related to the `User` class in the sandbox to the `CreateUserDto`.
5. Pay close attention that your field names are correct and match! So the field name from the object that you are passing needs to match the field you are checking for in your mongo condition. You are checking for `userType` -> make sure your `User` or `UserCreateDto` class also has the field `userType`. In your other question, the `User` class had a field named `type` only. That way the matching of course cannot work.

Hope this gets you closer to your solution :)